# Do I Adjust the handbrake cable before I fit and adjust new brake shoes Nissan Note 2006

Tags: brakes

2006 Nissan note handbrake adjustment, do I unadjust the handbrake before fitting new brake shoes

Comment: Is the hand brake connected to the shoes or the driveshaft ?  I don't know about Nissan , but  I replaced over 40  sets of shoes in GM cars and never  loosened a hand brake.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

There is a self-adjuster in the drum brake assembly (see image). Most drum brakes have a slot on the back side where you can use a flat head screwdriver to undo it.

[image: Brake drum assembly]

Most likely you will not be able to remove the brake drum (or get it back on) without undoing the self-adjuster. When you're done replacing the parts, put on the brake drum and test if the wheel spins. If it does, turn the self-adjuster a few clicks and check again. Keep doing this until you feel the shoes slightly rubbing aginst the drum. Then turn back 2 or 3 clicks and you're done. Make sure you also check the handbrake to see if it feels normal.